# SeleniumRC code to get message text of email and locate the perticular mail with/without using XPath

Tags: xpath, gmail, selenium-rc

I am new to Selenium RC and am using Selenium+Java+Eclipse.

I have a requirement to Open my Gmail and Click on an email, then read the email and click the links in the body part of that mail.

1. In standard mode of GMail, I am unable to locate any of the mail. Any clue how to do this? Below is the code I applied, but unsuccessfully.

   ```
   selenium.clickAt("/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a/span", "0,0");
   ```
2. In HTML mode of Gmail, using XPath I am unable to locate the particular mail every time because of new emails in the inbox. Any idea how to handle this?
3. Any idea how to get the message text of the mail? If I use `Selenium.getText("xpath")` then the message text will be changing with new emails in the inbox. How can I achieve this?

Is there any other way without using XPath?

Comment: Plzzzzzzzzzzzz?? Is there a bee around you?

Comment: This is actually against the [Gmail terms of service](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS?hl=en) see section 5.3 "You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers)"

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the xpath expression Selenium IDE has autogenerated for you. Make it more generic.

So, Instead of

```
/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a/span
```

Use (for instance)

```
//form//a/span
```

to grab all hyperlinks with a span tag, that are contained anywhere in a form.

This will return a list of spans. Then filter those entries, keep only those nodes that you need, and check for some condition.

You can also use

```
"//form//a/span[contains(text(),'" + linktext + "')]";
```

where linktext is the text you are looking for (sender name or mail-subject, I suppose)

Comment: Hi .. i tried as u said.. selenium.click("//form/a/span[contains(text(), 'hello find it' )]");

but its throwing error as 'com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Element //form/a/span[contains(text(), 'hello find it' )] not found

did i go wrong anywhere..???

Comment: In Gmail basic-html mode, this xpath expression selects mails with the subject line. //span/b[contains(text(),'has invited you to become friends')]     Gmail standard mode seems much more complicated, as it's javascript -only.